# How can I get the AppData directory in Xml

Tags: .net, xml, wpf

I am working on a project develop in WPF, I wanted to modify the .exe.config file so that it allows me to point to the AppData directory whatever the user of the application,  I used "% USERPROFILE% \ AppData "but it did not work.

CCould you tell me what is the command that will allow me to point to AppData file.

```
<add key="default_path" value= 
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\N.O.E\Affaires" />

<!-- Répertoire des affaires -->
<add key="affaires_path" value= 
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\N.O.E\Affaires" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to get the roaming user application data folder.

Comment: I changed "% USERPROFILE% \ AppData \ Roaming \ N.O.E \ Business" to "% Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)% \ Roaming \ N.O.E \ Business" but it did not work.     could you tell me how I use this command in my code ?;

Comment: This is a static method that returns the path string, so it can't be used as a static string. You'll need to call it in code-behind or in your view model. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.